# JQuery mobile: Close Collapsible div (or any div) when clicking outside

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page with multiple collapsible sections, like this:

Persona

Impresa

News

I want all collapsible div (including this one) on my page to collapse when I click outside of it.
I tried many of the generic solutions here on stackoverflow but each one has some bad side effects...
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//when a user clicks anywhere (unless the event is stopped from propagating) this will fire
$(document).delegate('.ui-page', 'click', function () {

    //if we trigger `collapse` on the collapsible widget, it will close
    $(this).find('.ui-collapsible').trigger('collapse');
});
```

This handles closing all the collapsible widgets on a page when the page is clicked. You then probably want to stop event bubbling from the collapsible widgets so when you open the widget it doesn't get closed as well:

```
//anytime a user clicks on a collapsible widget
$(document).delegate('.ui-collapsible', 'click', function (event) {

    //we stop the event from bubbling so it doesn't reach the `.ui-page` element and close the collapsible again
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Hgzpn/

Comment: Hi, I forgot to say that in each collapsible there is a list, and there are handlers for the click event for each <li>, with this solution the event from the list is stopped. In the function that stops the propagation I need something like if("element that rised the event is <li> in collapsable") don't stop the event.

Comment: Inside the event handler you can check that: `if (this.className == 'my-li-class') { ... }`, or you could do it by `tagName`: `if (this.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'li') { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

When click is triggered you could check if the mouse position is inside each of your collabpsible sections.

Something like:

```
if (section.X <= mouseX && mouseX <= section.x + section.width && section.y <= mouseY && mouseY <= section.y + section.height) //mouse is inside => don't collapse
else // mouse is outside => collapse
```

the code above is not javascript, but I'm sure you understand the ideea.

Answer (score 0):

Great tip.

I made some changes.

```
        //when a user clicks anywhere (unless the event is stopped from propagating) this will fire
        $(document).delegate('.ui-page', 'click', function () {

            //if we trigger `collapse` on the collapsible widget, it will close
            $(this).find('.ui-collapsible').trigger('collapse');
        });


        //When clicking on a collapsible, close the remainig collapsibles
        $('.ui-collapsible').bind('expand', function (dropdown) {

            $(document).find('.ui-collapsible').each( function (number, element) {

                if (dropdown.currentTarget != element)
                {
                    $(this).trigger('collapse');
                }

            });
        });
```